# Can I generate a "merge tool viewable" diff output with git?

Tags: git, merge, diff

For small chunks of code, I can manage writing:

`git diff SOURCE_FILE`

but when it gets past a number of lines, it gets difficult to watch. Is there someway of generating two files, one being the staged one, the other containing the modifications, and compare them using a tool like WinMerge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure an extern diff command using the environment variable GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF. The command get calles with the arguments `newfile oldfile ...` e.g.

```
 $ GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=echo git diff
 a.txt /tmp/QLpGlH_a.txt bd304d959129af4d8b920f1562e09ead75aab379 100755 a.txt 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100755
```

Use `git diff --help` for details

Comment: Cool! It's a lot better now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to set up the external diff tool and use that with [`git difftool`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html) instead of calling `git diff` (see section *CONFIG VARIABLES* in the manpage for [`git difftool`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html)).

To see the configuration for using Araxis Merge as diff tool, see the [Araxis support pages](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#msysGit). The settings made there should be easily adoptable for the tool you're going to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pretty Diff API and simply input a URI for each code location.

http://prettydiff.com/api.php